# octave: load many functions from single file

Tags: octave, read-eval-print-loop

How can I put multiple functions in one file and later get access to all of them in the octave interpreter ? I don't want to have a thousand files and want to group functions together. I'd like something like 'import' in python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is called “script files”, defined there: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Script-Files.html

Answer (score 9):

Once you have saved all your function definitions in a single script file, use `source("filename")` to have access to these functions within the interpreter.