# Load Multiple Functions from a Single File in Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, user-defined-functions, aliases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to define more than one function per file in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569933/is-it-possible-to-define-more-than-one-function-per-file-in-matlab)

Is it possible to load multiple functions from the same .m file in Matlab? I find it cumbersome to create a single file for each function for many small alias utility functions. I have already tried [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068599/octave-load-many-functions-from-single-file) which is allowed Octave, but not in my Matlab. I get the following error:

```
??? Error: File: /home/per/Documents/MATLAB/aliases.m Line: 6 Column: 1
Function definitions are not permitted in this context.
```

My `aliases.m` file currently contains

```
% Prevent Octave from thinking that this
% is a function file:

1;

function y = isvariable(x)
%Return non-zero if x is a function.
    y = exist(x, 'var');
end

function y = isfile(x)
%Return non-zero if x is a function.
    y = exist(x, 'file');
end

function y = isdir(x)
%Return non-zero if x is a function.
    y = exist(x, 'dir');
end

function y = isbuiltin(x)
%Return non-zero if x is a function.
    y = exist(x) == 5;
end
```

Comment: Yes, clearly a duplicate. Should do some kind of merging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible, each m-file contains exactly one MATLAB function (you can have nested or sub-functions, but they are not accessible  outside of the file).

If you are concerned about putting too much stuff on the global scope, think about OOP and [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748302/what-is-the-closest-thing-matlab-has-to-namespaces).