# Can I load variables & functions from Octave script file into global scope from an if test?

Tags: scripting, global-variables, octave

I have a script that performs a lot of computation on startup, and defines some functions, and I want to ensure it is all loaded when I run other scripts. I'm running `Octave 5.1.0` configured for `x86_64-w64-mingw32`.

I initially tried call the script only if one of its variables didn't `exist('varName')`. That doesn't seem to work, so I marked a lot of the variables `global`, but they still aren't loaded into global, and the functions aren't either. The script works well if I call it from the top level of the REPL or the other script's top level (but not inside an `if` test). I also checked out other questions like [octave: load many functions from single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068599/octave-load-many-functions-from-single-file).

This is what I want to do:

```
global all;
if (!exist('all'))
  prepareData
endif
```

I am wondering how to expose the global variables and functions in the `prepareData` script only the first time it is run.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the question writing process, it became clear to me that I can simply put the `if (!exist('all'))` into the original script to prevent it from loading the data multiple times. So now in the `prepareData` script I just put my expensive data loading inside this:

```
global all;
if (!exist('all') || length(all) < 1);
  # Expensive load calls
endif
```

and in the consuming script I can call simply:

```
prepareData;

# Happily use data
```

Comment: The additional `length(all) < 1` check is because the `global all;` gives the variable a dimension of `0x0` with value `[]`.

Comment: Note that `all` is name of a builtin function.